# boolean value of NA is too ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column with a few conditions. One being if the 'TierType' is different than the cell below. Second is if the 'ID' is the same as the row below. If these conditions are met, I would like to return 1 and if not 0. This is what returns and I felt it might be because of NaN values, but I deleted any NaN values in the data. Any idea why I would get the error message 'TypeError: boolean values of NA is ambiguous' (also shown in image)[image]

```
tier_change = df_AC['TierType'] != df_AC['TierType'].shift(1)
sub_ID = df_AC["Subscriber Contact's My Avid ID"] == df_AC["Subscriber Contact's My Avid ID"].shift(1) 
df_AC['Tier_Type_Change_Date'] = np.where((tier_change) & (sub_ID), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Can you run the command `print(tier_change.isna().sum(), sub_ID.isna().sum())` and post the output?

Comment: @NickODell Yes! I found 0 NaN for tier_change and 1 NaN for sub_ID. 
Return:
0 1

Comment: So you _didn't_ delete all the NaN values in the data.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

The expression `(tier_change) & (sub_ID)` is boolean.

Error `builtins.TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous` is raised where there is a missing value in a boolean expression.

In Pandas missing value is represented by `pd.NA`.

For instance, to reproduce the error in the Shell :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> bool(pd.NA)
...
builtins.TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

> Since the actual value of an NA is unknown, it is ambiguous to convert
> NA to a boolean value.

From documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na)

Notice that Pandas missing value is not exactly the same as empty Numpy Nan value, as we could check as follows in the Shell:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bool(np.nan)
True
```

**A proposed solution**

Replace the empty values by what suits best to you by using Pandas `fillna()` method to solve the issue.

**Properties Tests**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Empty Pandas Value': pd.NA, 'Empty Numpy Value': np.nan}])

print(df)
#   Empty Pandas Value  Empty Numpy Value
# 0               <NA>                NaN

# Replace by 0
zeros = df.fillna(0)
#    Empty Pandas Value  Empty Numpy Value
# 0                   0                0.0

# Or replace by NaN
nans = df.fillna(np.nan)
#    Empty Pandas Value  Empty Numpy Value
# 0                 NaN                NaN

#  ------- Boolean TEST 1 ------- 
df['Empty Pandas Value'] != df['Empty Numpy Value']
# 0    True
# dtype: bool

# ------- Boolean TEST 2 ------- 
df['Empty Pandas Value'].astype(bool)
# ...
# builtins.TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

# ------- Boolean TEST 3 ------- 
df['Empty Numpy Value'].astype(bool)
# 0    True
# Name: Empty Numpy Value, dtype: bool
```